# Присвоение класса элемента при клике

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js, click

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
const clicksertif = document.querySelector('.sertif-img');
if (clicksertif) {
    clicksertif.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        
        clicksertif.classList.toggle('sertif-zoom');
    });
}
```

Суть в том, что есть куча элементов (слайды) с классом `sertif-img`. Мне нужно чтобы при клике на один их таких элементов присваивался класс именно для того элемента по которому кликнули. Это можно реализовать? Вообще у меня слайдер `slick`. И мне необходимо, чтобы при клике на изображение оно увеличивалось (типо на весь экран), а при повторном клике уменьшалось обратно. Может я вообще не правильно пытаюсь это реализовать? Может это делается иначе?

Comment: Пример дайте, совсем не понятно о чём именно речь.

Comment: Советую вами почитать про делегирование событий

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите, чтобы на каждом элементе был прослушиватель, то для начала все их нужно получить, а уже потом вешать на каждый элемент прослушиватель. Например так:

```
// Получаем все элементы с классом .sertif-img
const clicksertif = document.querySelectorAll(".sertif-img");

if (clicksertif.length) {
  // Для каждого элемента навешиваем свой прослушиватель
  clicksertif.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      this.classList.toggle("sertif-zoom");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Длину можно и не проверять

Comment: @EzioMercer Да? А что вернет проверка, если нодлист будет пустой, без элементов?

Comment: Пустой нодлист вернётся

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что будет `true` или `false` с пустым нодлистом, если не проверять длину как вы предлагаете?

Comment: Что будет `true` или `false` если не проверять?

Comment: У вас есть предположение?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141699/discussion-between-eziomercer-and--).